# Find all progids to dispatch win32com object?

Tags: python, win32com

There are instructions on dispatching win32 com objects such as:

```py
win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
```

I'm trying to go through the process of identifying the progid but haven't been able to do so. One source suggests to browse objects with Python. So if I run this:

```py
from win32com.client import combrowse
combrowse.main(modal = True)
```

It shows a Python Object Browser as below.

[image]

However, it's not clear how to go from the items in this window to identify the progid strings. For example, these are part of the methods listed in the "Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library" folder (the list is too long that the screenshot can't get it all):

[image]

So my question is: If the method above is a decent one, can you help by providing an example how to use it to find progid of an app, say, Excel? Otherwise, please suggest if there is a better method to identify all progids.

Comment: Use the RegistrEditor, and search under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. You will find all the ProgIds listed there eg `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Application` at the top level, with a sub-key of CLSID.  This gives you a list of the all ProgIds registered on the system: there is then some guesswork around which one you want!